# Can't select the same item from listbox twice in a row - windows phone 8 C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, listbox, selecteditem, longlistselector

I'm using SelectedChanged event in ListBox and LongListSelector but it is not fire when I choose the same item for a second time in a row, and that is true.
But, I need to make an action if I selected the same item more than one time.

I find a solution which set the SelectedIndex = -1 in ListBox , and set the SelectedItem = null in LongListSelector.

But, It is not work with me as I need the data of the SelectedItem in another view.

How Can I do this?

Thanks,

Comment: That's not how it works, so trying to add meaning to someone selecting the same item twice isn't the best idea.  Better to [edit] and add a description of *what you are attempting to accomplish* by adding meaning to selecting the same thing twice in a row.

Comment: Can't understand you, you don't get what I ask for?

Comment: What are you trying to do when the user selects the same item more than one time?  What is your goal?

Comment: Navigating to another view to view selected item details

Comment: Reset SelectedItem when you navigate back.

Comment: Nothing change, the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach of setting SelectedIndex = -1 in ListBox , and set the SelectedItem = null is correct.
Only you need to do this in the 'navigationto' event of the page that holds the listview. That way you'll only clear it when you are again on the list page.

Answer (score 0):

I try another way and it is good with me. Instead of using (selectedChanged) event, I used Tap() event.